# MPD Interface that supports voting?

Tags: linux, mpd

I'm looking for a web interface other that ampache that can stream to mpd and allows users to vote on what they want to hear. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "[Zina Is Not Andromeda](http://www.pancake.org/zina)": I use it with Drupal, but I think you could use it as a standalone as well.